# ngOnChanges fails to trigger on change of Input

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

My angular component is like below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'request-Component'
    templateUrls: './request.component.html'
    styleUrls: ['./request.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
     @Input() filters: FilterMetadata;
 
     constructor(private service: RequestService){} 

     ngOnInit(): void {this.service.GetRequests(this.filters);}

     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
         console.info('ngOnChanges: ', changes['filters']);
         this.service.GetRequests(this.filters);
     }
}
```

Below is how I am injecting this component in the caller:

```
<request-Component [filters]='filtersData'></request-Component>
```

Below is the FilterMetadata interface:

```
export default interface FilterMetadata{
    country: string;
    state: string;
    city: string;
}
```

Below is how the input to child is set in the caller component:

```
setFiltersData() {
    this.FiltersData = {
        country: 'testCountry',
        state: 'testState',
        city: 'testCity'
    }
}
```

I am able to solve this by explicitly implement a getter and setter on the Input in the child component but I want to know why ngOnChanges is not detecting the change.

Comment: it should trigger. moreover you should be able to call GetRequests only in ngOnChanges, because it would trigger at sart as wel

Comment: Can you double check that the code pasted is copied correctly? You have a variable `FiltersData` (uppercase F) being updated instead of `filtersData` (lowercase f) which would mean your data is never passed to the child component

Comment: @Andrei - onInit supports the call as well as it can be null or preset. But anyway, the real issue is it's not working

Comment: @nate-kumar - sorry for the typo, it is filtersData. But that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnChanges` method is triggered exclusively when there is a modification in the Input property that originates from a template binding. However, if you manually assign a value to the property like `object = {key: newValue}`, **this occurs outside the change detection cycle**, and you must inform Angular explicitly that a change has been made.

Besides getter/setter approach you can use:

```
updateNewData(newValue) {
  this.object= newValue;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Luckily, `ngOnChanges` will be invoked.